# error in updating weight in a tree from leaf to root

Tags: python, json, algorithm, tree

I have a json tree

```
{"reply": 0, "id": 1, "children": [{"reply": 1, "id": 2, "children": [{"reply": 1, "id": 3, "children": [{"reply": 1, "id": 4, "children": []}]}]}, {"reply": 0, "id": 5, "children": []}]}
```

I have to assign weights such that from leaf to root:

1. All the leaf nodes get weight of 0.1
2. If a node has one child: Then the weight of the node becomes 0.1*weight of its single child
3. If a node has two or more children then weight of that node is:

   weight of its child1*weight of child2*....childn*0.1*0.2

   e.g the output is final weights of node:

   4: 0.1, 5: 0.1, 3: 0.1*0.1, 2: (0.1*0.1*0.1) 1: 0.1*0.2(0.1*0.1*0.1*0.1)`

I am working with a code in python

I am getting a keyerror 2 while updating weight:

The exception is Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cc1.py", line 42, in 
    weight[par]=weight[par]*weight[child_of[par][i]]
KeyError: 2

I have three dictionaries:

```
import json
from collections import deque
def generate_children(tree):
    queue = deque()
    queue.append((tree, None))
    while queue:
       node, parent = queue.pop()
       children = []
    for child in node['children']:
        queue.append((child, node['id']))
        children.append(child['id'])
    parent_of[node['id']]=parent
    child_of[node['id']]=children
    no_child_of[node['id']]=len(child_of[node['id']])
    yield node['id'], parent, children

f=open('tree_json','r')
for line in f:
    tree=json.loads(line)
    parent_of={}
    child_of={}
    no_child_of={}
    weight={}
    q = list(generate_children(tree))
    #assigning weights to leaf
    for c in no_child_of.keys():
        if no_child_of[c]==0:
            weight[c]=0.1
    # assigning weight to the parent
    for w in weight.keys():
        par=parent_of[w]
        n=len(child_of[par])
        if n > 1:
            weight[par]=0.2
            for i in range(n):
                weight[par]=weight[par]*weight[child_of[par][i]]
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a minimal example of `node`, `parent` and `children` which would then enable us to recreate your keyerror.

Comment: @Martin Evans: the problem comes when it tries to update weight of root and when the weight of one of its children is not known. Please help, I am stuck

Comment: Martin is asking you to provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code you've provided so far is incomplete (you don't show what `node`, `parent`, `children` actually _are_), which means we can't run it to reproduce your problem

Comment: Oh, and _also_ - when you "get a keyerror", an exception is being thrown, and you should see a stack trace with line numbers. Please show the exception and stack trace, and indicate the lines in your code corresponding to the line numbers, if it isn't clear.

Comment: @Martin Evans: given the complete code with an input. Please help

Comment: @Useless: Updated the question. please see

Comment: And the exception stacktrace?

Comment: Are you sure the indenting on your code is correct?

Comment: @Useless: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cc1.py", line 42, in <module>
    weight[par]=weight[par]*weight[child_of[par][i]]   Keyerror:2

Comment: OK, so one of the keys used in that line is `2`, and it isn't in the container you're trying to access. Either stick some print statements in, or wrap a `try:/except:` block around that line, and find out which key is missing from which container.

Comment: @Martin Evans: Yes. The indentation is correct.

Comment: @Useless: I know 2 is missing as the values are assigned from leaf and then the values are assigned to parent. since 6 is leaf, 1 is been assigned value and 2 has not been assigned yet.

Comment: actually it should first assign the value to the parent whose all childrens have weights. I am not able to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I think in your code you are trying to access weight of a node that is not been assigned yet.

Check the following pseudo code. Hope it will solve your purpose. 
I am assuming you know the root element.

```
for each node in tree
    weight[node] = 0;

current_node = root;
while(weight[root] = 0){
   if(no_child_of(current_node) = 0){
       weight[current_node] = 0.1;
       current_node = parent_of[current_node];
   }else{
      boolean all_child_weighted = true;
      total_weight = 1;
      for each (child[i] of current_node){
         if(weight[child_of[current_node][i]] = 0){
             all_child_weighted = false;
             current_node = child_of[current_node][i];  
             break; 
         }else{
             total_weight = total_weight * weight[child_of[current_node][i]];
         } 
      }   
      if(all_child_weighted){
          if(no_child_of(current_node) = 1){
              weight[current_node] = 0.1*weight[child_of[current_node][1]];
          }else{
              weight[current_node] = total_weight * 0.1 * 0.2;
          }
          current_node = parent_of(current_node);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: @Somabatra: root may have any number of children. In the pesudocode you have given it seems root has only two children

Comment: Please edit if a root has n number of children. This considers two children for root

Comment: I just followed your statement "If a node has two or more children then weight of that node is:

weight of its child1*weight of child2*0.1*0.2" editting as per your requirements

Comment: Thanks. Will try the code and let u know. Thanks again

Comment: This is not working as it is never assigning weight to leaf nodes. In the first If condition it is checking whether the number of root are zero or not.

Comment: If you are talking about first if (not the condition in while), then it will go to else and  the first child of root will be the current node.

Comment: before going to the loop, assign weight of everything to 0.